# Drupal ajax call within form

Tags: 7

I am trying to call ajax call within form. here is my code

```
<?php

function clicktell_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //print_r($form);

    if($form_id=='user_register_form') {

        $form['choice_wrapper']['poll_more'] = array(

            '#type' => 'submit',

            '#value' => t('More choices'),

            '#description' => t("If the amount of boxes above isn't enough, click here to add more choices."),

            '#weight' => 1,
            "#executes_submit_callback" => FALSE,


            '#ajax' => array(

                'callback' => 'poll_choice_js',

                'wrapper' => 'poll-choices',

                'method' => 'replace',

                'effect' => 'fade',

            ),);


    }
}

function poll_choice_js($form, $form_state) {
    print_r($form_state);
    return $form['choice_wrapper']['choice'];

}
```

when i click on more choice button it is not calling poll_choice_js function. i checked this in firebug but didn't get any result

Thanks

Comment: What is `choice_wrapper` ?

Comment: nothing. we can ignore it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  return

function poll_choice_js($form, $form_state) {
    return('something');
    return $form['choice_wrapper']['choice'];

}

Answer (score 0):

For the **ajax callback**  and **hook_form_alter()** to function you should **clear the caches** from the performance link.
Also you should change the following

```
return $form['choice_wrapper']['poll_more'];
```

Comment: no it is not working